# Sikuli: onAppear works regardless of the pattern presence

Tags: java, python, jython, sikuli

As far as I understand onAppear is to evoke the handler in case the Pattern is on the screen.
However, when I'm running:

```
paste(Pattern("123.png").targetOffset(-1,37),"testText")
wait(2)
onAppear("456.png", popup("Text1"))
```

Pop-up appears always, even if the pattern `456.png` is not on the screen

Could you please advise, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the observer call.
You can read more on observers in sikuli [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.onAppear)

Basically what you need to do is add the following line after your code:

```
observe([your desired timeout in seconds], [background = True/False])
```

And don't forget to add the stopObserver() call if you don't set timeout.